# Sort Chronologically MMM-YY Date - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a month column in MMM-YY format over two years (Month = FORMAT('Actual (2)'[Date].[Date],"mmm-yy") and I have sorted by another column called FiscalMonth (FiscalMonth = (If( Month([Date]) >= 7 , Month([Date]) - 6,Month([Date]) + 6 )), which represents our fiscal calendar. When I create a viz though I get the months from both years in order and not the months from the first year first and then the second year's months.

[pbx viz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr6Tg.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a sort column to solve this.

```
MonthSort = CONVERT(FORMAT('YourDateTable']'Date', 'yyyymm'), INTEGER)
```

Then, on your tool bar, "Column Tools" tab, tell PowerBI to "Sort Column By" this value. This uses the display you want and the sort you need.

[image]